If $h:A\to B$ is an injection then prove the inequality$|A|\le|B|$ holds, where $\le$ is the usual order into $\mathbf{Ord}$.
Let's we assume there is an injection $h$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$. I am trying to prove the inequality below holds
$$
|A|\le|B|
$$
I elaborated on what follows but it fails.

So let be $\varphi$ a bijection from $|A|$ to $A$ and $\psi$ a bijection from $B$ to $|B|$: supposing the inequality
$$
|B|<|A|
$$
then
$$
f:=(\psi\circ h\circ\varphi):|A|\to|B|\subseteq|A|
$$
would be a bijection from $|A|$ to any subset $\Lambda$ of $|A|$.
Now $\Lambda$ is well ordered by $\le$ so that it is equipotent to an unique initial ordinal $\lambda$: so if $g$ is a bijection from $\Lambda$ to $\lambda$ then $g\circ f$ is a bijection from $|A|$ to $\lambda$ and thus the equality
$$
|A|=\lambda
$$
holds.

Unfortunately, I was not able to argue a contradiction by the last equality, so I thought to put here a specific question where I ask for a solution: could someone help me, please?
REMARK
I use the present statement to prove that any infinite ordinal is an element of the Hartog's sequences $(\omega_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbf{Ord}}$.

The proof of the property depends on what you already know and are allowed to use.
The following is a simple and yet quite general argument, which can be "optimized" if you make your context more explicit.
Let $\varphi \colon |A| \to A$ and $\psi \colon B \to |B|$ be bijections.
Since $h \colon A \to B$ is an injection, $\psi \circ h \circ \varphi \colon |A| \to |B|$ is an injection too, and this implies that $|A| \subseteq |B|$
since $|A|$ and $|B|$ are cardinals (see here for two different proofs).
As $|A|$ and $|B|$ are ordinals, from $|A| \subseteq |B|$ it follows that $|A|\in |B|$ or $|A| = |B|$, that is, $|A| \leq |B|$.
Remark. I crucially used the fact that every set is equipotent to a cardinal (to claim the existence of $\varphi$ and $\psi$). From what you write, it seems to me that you assume that fact.

Note that when you say (the emphasis is mine)

would be a bijection from $|A|$ to any subset $\Lambda$ of $|A|$

I don't see why, unless you mean "to some subset $\Lambda$ of $|A|$" meaning that $|B|$ is such a $\Lambda$.

All clear: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance! :-)

@AntonioMariaDiMauro - You're welcome!
